# Installing and Running Drupal in Subfolder - Beginner

Tags: installation

I am trying to do a redesign on a drupal site. I added a subfolder via an ftp client (example.com/devsite) and manually uploaded the extracted drupal7 files. One would think that going to example.com/devsite or example.com/devsite/install.php would be the next step in accessing the subfolder files, but im only getting 404/page not found error messages when i navigate to this URL.

I'm new to drupal and feel like this should be an easy fix...but dang is it frustrating. HELP!

I have read "[How to get Drupal 7 installed in a sub-folder / sub-directory properly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73782/how-to-get-drupal-7-installed-in-a-sub-folder-sub-directory-properly)" already - i'm having a difficult time deciphering what steps to take from this post. I need the original site example.com to be live, but example.com/devsite to be viewable as well.

Comment: this post lost me at " I already modified the .htaccess in the parent drupal installation to ignore the sub-folder and i also set the $base_url in the sub-directory drupal installation."   I am VERY new and having the hardest time decoding which steps to take to get the subfolder running. :/

Comment: What do you mean by subfolder, you are trying to create sub-domain for your website?

Comment: make sure the sub folder has the correct permissions - try adding a dummy 'hello world' html file to the sub folder and try accessing that

Comment: Next time, when asking questions, please try to include all relevant information. If you already read that other question, please tell us. Let us know what you tried, what worked, where you got stuck, what you didn't understand. That will make your question a new one, not a duplicate. You can still edit edit your question to add all this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read "How to get Drupal 7 installed in a sub-folder / sub-directory properly?" already - i'm having a difficult time deciphering what steps to take from this post.

Your problem is not a Drupal problem. It is a file permissions problem. It is probably caused by you using ftp to create the sub-direactory to hold Drupal.

> but im only getting 404/page not found error messages when i navigate to this URL.

This means that the the directory you've created with ftp, and/or the files you've uploaded in that directory is *not readable* by the webserver user.

If you have access to the command line interface (CLI), you may need to use *chown* to make sure the Drupal directory and files are owned by the webserver user, or at least use *chmod* to make sure they're readable by the webserver user.

However, since you use ftp, I assume that you have not CLI access to your installation? In that case, you need to contact customer support at your hosting provider to learn what tools exist to change the read permissions of files and directories to be readable by the webserver user.

> this post lost me at " I already modified the .htaccess in the parent drupal installation to ignore the sub-folder and i also set the $base_url in the sub-directory drupal installation."

That is just noise in the question.  You need to read the *upvoted answer* to that question for the solution.

In fact, you should ignore *all* the stuff about modifying `.htaccess` in the duplicate issue.  I am no idea why the person who wrote it believes this is relevant. Each Drupal installation has its own `.htaccess` in its own directory, and the one that comes with Drupal is fine provided you do a clean install. The simple fact is that there is *nothing* special about installing Drupal in a subfolder.  You need to get the directory and file permissions correct tho' - and using ftp to set things up may have caused the permissions to be wrong.