# How do I create a site inside another one?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I have a Drupal site (example.com). There is some content, and there is a page at `example.com/projects/abc`.

What I want to do is create another site on `example.com/projects/abc/NEWSITE`.

**How can I do that?**

Normally, I can create folders via FTP such as projects->abc->NEWSITE, but there is content on example.com/projects example.com/projects/abc.

Comment: I think this is the reason why sub domains are used, `abc.example.com`, to prevent url conflicts.

Comment: Are you aware of the documentation that drupal provides regarding [multisites](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base)?

Comment: @mchar, yes but I don't want to use multisite, because these are completely different sites and don't want to use a single installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but usually not really recommended solution - as we have subdomains/multisites in Drupal.

But basicly only thing that will probably need small adjustments is .htaccess,
make sure to edit RewriteBase variable. Check out these links:

Same/Similar topics here:

[How to get Drupal 7 installed in a sub-folder / sub-directory properly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73782/how-to-get-drupal-7-installed-in-a-sub-folder-sub-directory-properly)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122488/a-drupal-site-inside-another-drupal-subdirectory

https://www.drupal.org/node/600966

Configuring .htaccess to ignore specific subfolders: https://www.drupal.org/node/30334

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718406/how-to-exclude-a-folder-on-drupal-site-so-that-drupal-does-not-recognise-it-its

Also if You decide to go for multisite -> read this one: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-in-subdirectories

Hope this will help You :) Good luck!